# SQL Update query not completed

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I made a SQL query to update registers on a table. The table has about 15 million registers. The update statement is like:

```
UPDATE temp_conafe
  set apoyo = trim(apoyo)
  where cve_status like '%APOYO%';
```

I keep checking the field **v$transaction.used_ured** to see if the query is rolling forward or backwards but when the number of records reach to more than 15 millions the query starts rolling backwards.

- How do I get the update to complete successfully?

I'm not the DBA, just a programmer, but I can't keep developing till that thing updates my registers.

Comment: It sounds like you might be running out of log space to do the change.  Consider chunking your update so you run 10 smaller updates, using some other field than `cve_status`.  Also consider whether you really need to trim the data; can you not arrange to strip the trailing blanks in the client code?  If the data type is CHAR (rather than VARCHAR2), then the TRIM is pointless; the data will be stored with trailing blanks anyway.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for your advise, I'll check all that. I was thinking about the space too, but want to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if your transaction is to big. Try to add another limiting clause in the where. If you have a Id field you can add something like this:

```
where cve_status like '%APOYO%' 
AND id > 1 AND id < 100000
```

You need to run it multiple times an change the range accordingly. If this is not an option you have to talk to your DBA and ask him to give you more resources.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to make my transaction shorter and also talk to my DBA cause we are always making data analysis with such large data.